# Can my parsec parser write deprecation messages?

Tags: haskell, parsec

I have a DSL, and a parser for it written in Haskell with the Parsec package. Now I want to deprecate a specific language feature of the DSL. In the next release, I want the parser to accept both the new and the old syntax, but I want the parser to spawn a deprecation message. I could not find how to do this. Is this possible, and if so, how can this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of emitting messages during parsing, it would be better to return extra information at the end of parsing: whether or not deprecated syntax was encountered.

The [`ParsecT`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.14.0/docs/Text-Parsec.html#t:ParsecT) type admits a type parameter for state set by the user during parsing:

> ParsecT s u m a is a parser with stream type s, **user state type u**, underlying monad m and return type a. Parsec is strict in the user state.

The user state can be set with [`putState`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.14.0/docs/Text-Parsec.html#v:putState) and [`modifyState`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.14.0/docs/Text-Parsec.html#v:modifyState). It can be obtained using [`getState`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.14.0/docs/Text-Parsec.html#v:getState).

Most parsec combinators are polymorphic on the user state. Most combinators for your own DSL should be, as well. But parsers for deprecated parts of the syntax should set a "flag" in your user state.

Something like this:

```
import Text.Parsec
import Text.Parsec.Char
import Data.Functor.Identity

type Parser = ParsecT [Char] Bool Identity -- using a Bool state

myParser :: Parser Char
myParser = 
    try (do char 'a' 
            putState True 
            char 'b')
    <|> 
    try (do char 'a' 
            char 'c')

main :: IO ()
main = do
    print $ runParser ((,) <$> myParser <*> getState)  False "" "ab"
    print $ runParser ((,) <$> myParser <*> getState)  False "" "ac"
-- results:
-- Right ('b',True)
-- Right ('c',False)
```

Of course, instead of a simple boolean flag, it would be better to put more information into the state.

Notice that state set by a sub-parser is "forgotten" if the sub-parser backtracks. That is the correct behavior for our purposes: otherwise, we would get "false positives" triggered by branches that are ultimately discarded.

---

A common alternative to [parsec](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.14.0) is [megaparsec](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/megaparsec). The latter doesn't allow for user-defined state [in the parser type itself](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/megaparsec-9.0.0/docs/Text-Megaparsec.html#t:ParsecT), but it can be emulated using a [`StateT`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.6.2/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-RWS-Strict.html) transformer over the [`ParsecT`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/megaparsec-9.0.0/docs/Text-Megaparsec.html#t:ParsecT) type.

Comment: I think a `WriterT` variant like [this one](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.6.2/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Writer-CPS.html) would be more appropriate than the totally wild `StateT`. Deprecations can't be cancelled later.